# Implementation of renewcommand in algorithms package

Tags: algorithms

I am using the `algorithms` package, but am not being properly able to convert "Require" to say, something like "Parameters", using the `\renewcommand` macro. Can anyone please show how and in which part of the program to implement the `\renewcommand` to make this simple change?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you show us what you have done so far?

Answer (score 2):

The `algorithmic` package does

```
\newcommand{\REQUIRE}{\item[\algorithmicrequire]}
\newcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Require:}}
```

so you can redefine `\algorithmicrequire`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Parameters:}}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithmic}
\REQUIRE $x \neq 0$ and $n \geq 0$
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

[image]